# Designing a Markov chain given its steady state probabilities

Tags: probability, markov-chains, steady-state

As explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain, for a three state Markov Chain with the transition matrix given as

$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0.9 & 0.075 & 0.025 \\
0.15 & 0.8 & 0.05 \\
0.25 & 0.25 & 0.5
\end{bmatrix},$

the steady state probabilities can be found from

$\lim_{N\to \infty } \, P^N=
\begin{bmatrix}
 0.625 & 0.3125 & 0.0625 \\
 0.625 & 0.3125 & 0.0625 \\
 0.625 & 0.3125 & 0.0625 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$

Now my Question is, how can I find a valid transition matrix P for any other steady state probabilities, lets say for example $[0.3, 0.5, 0.2]?$.
Preferably with P containing only elements that are nice to work with by hand.

Comment: Knowing the steady-state distribution gives you one eigenvalue/eigenvector pair. That leaves you with two other eigenvalues with associated (possibly complex) eigenvectors to select. The eigenvalues are restricted to have modulus $\le1$, but otherwise you’ve got a several degrees of freedom to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are many possible Markov chains we can design, but here is an approach that generalizes well, is easy to construct, and gives a Markov chain that's easy to solve.

For the specific example where we want to get the limiting distribution
$$
   (\pi_1, \pi_2, \pi_3) = (0.3, 0.5, 0.2)
$$
take the transition matrix
$$
   P = \begin{bmatrix}
       0.5 & 0.5 & 0 \\
       0.3 & 0.5 & 0.2 \\
       0 & 0.5 & 0.5
   \end{bmatrix}.
$$
To solve for the stationary distribution here, note that we can only get from state $1$ to states $\{2,3\}$ via the $1 \to 2$ transition, and we can only get from states $\{2,3\}$ via the $2 \to 1$ transition. In any infinite sample from this Markov chain, these transitions must alternate, and therefore the limiting rate of these transitions must be equal. This gives us the equation
$$
   0.5 \pi_1 = 0.3 \pi_2.
$$
By the same token, the $2 \to 3$ and $3 \to 2$ transitions must alternate, giving us the equation
$$
   0.2 \pi_2 = 0.5 \pi_3.
$$
These equations, together with $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \pi_3 = 1$, uniquely determine the limiting distribution; also, it is easy to check that the desired vector $(0.3, 0.5, 0.2)$ satisfies them, since
$$
   0.5 \cdot 0.3 = 0.3 \cdot 0.5 \qquad \text{and} \qquad 0.2 \cdot 0.5 = 0.5 \cdot 0.2.
$$
To generalize this construction to get an $n$-state Markov chain with limiting distribution $(\pi_1, \pi_2, \dots, \pi_n)$, simply set

- $P_{i,i+1} = \pi_{i+1}$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, n-1$;
- $P_{i,i-1} = \pi_{i-1}$ for $i = 2, 3, \dots, n$;
- Put all remaining probability for each state in $P_{i,i}$, leaving all other transitions at $0$.

In this Markov chain, you can only go from state $i$ to the "adjacent" states $i\pm1$, or stay at $i$. By the argument we've already seen, the limiting rate of the transitions $i \to i+1$ and $i+1 \to i$ must be equal, giving us the equations
$$
   \pi_i P_{i,i+1} = \pi_{i+1} P_{i+1,i}
$$
for each $i = 1, 2, \dots, n$. Together with the equation $\pi_1 + \pi_2 + \dots + \pi_n = 1$, these equations uniquely determine the limiting disribution, and it's easy to check that the limiting distribution we want satisfies them.

Some more general comments:

- These simplified equations for solving for the limiting distribution are known as the *time-reversibility equations*. For a general Markov chain, the system of equations $\pi_i P_{i,j} = \pi_j P_{j,i}$ (for all $i,j$) won't necessarily have a solution, but if it does, that solution is always a stationary distribution.
- This assumes that there is no state $i$ for which we want $\pi_i = 0$. If we do want that, then leave $i$ out of the chain at first, and later add it back in with a probability-$1$ transition to some other state, doesn't matter which.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is sufficient for me but I also wonder if there is a more general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\pi$, you can solve a system of linear equations for $P$:
\begin{align}
\pi_j &= \sum_i \pi_i P_{ij} &\text{for all $j$} \\
\sum_j P_{ij} &= 1 &\text{for all $i$} \\
P_{ij} &\ge \epsilon & \text{for all $i$ and $j$}
\end{align}
where $\epsilon > 0$ is some small constant (to guarantee that the resulting Markov chain is irreducible, aperiodic, and positive recurrent and hence has a limiting distribution).